# Sending data between local game server and remote hosted server

Tags: sockets, networking, shared-hosting

Lets say I have a **web server** that is hosted within a vServer of a hosting company and a **game server** that I have running locally at home.

I now want to run a webpage on the **web server** that can bi-directionally share information with the **game server**, e.g. sending in-game commands from an Admin panel and collecting responses. So something like:

*[local game server]* <--- **PROTOCOL** ---> *[web server]*

Which protocol/technology would I use here/would be recommended?

Comment: Did you write the game server yourself? Or are you stuck with the protocols that a game company's server supports? If so, which game?

Comment: @user253751 Game server runs Minecraft and I made a local Python program that can interact with the server (send commands, recieve feedback) through Minecraft's RCON.

Comment: so, does using RCON solve your problem? Does RCON not work over the Internet, is that why you're asking?

Comment: I phrased my comment wrong: The python program locally interacts with the game server, not the web server, sorry! RCON directly between web server and game server unfortunately wouldn't work because Minecraft's implementation doesn't support things like starting the Minecraft server instance.

Comment: I use RCON for in-game commands and other scripts for restarting, stopping and starting the local instance. This runs through the Python script. I need to interact between the Python script on the game server and the web server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution other than RCON, there are a few standard solutions.

One would be to use HTTP, where either the web server (probably the easiest) or the game server acts as a listener. If the web server is the listener, the game server can "poll" the server with HTTP requests to get updates. See: long polling

Another solution is to use sockets which can open a bidirectional stream between the servers. This option might take a bit longer to implement (you'd want to implement reconnection), but would be the better solution for high frequency data transfer between the two servers.

Based on your example use case, I would lean towards the first as it would probably be simpler to implement.